# Manipulation system of equation

Tags: algebraic-manipulation

I apologize for the banality of my question...
Suppose we have two equations:

```
b=a*x+l;
y=3x+2
```

How can I have b as a function of y?

Comment: Look up [`Eliminate`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Eliminate.html) and notice the proper syntax for equations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you were looking for?

```
In[4]:= Solve[y == 3 x + 2, x]

Out[4]= {{x -> 1/3 (-2 + y)}}

In[5]:= b = a*x + l /. x :> 1/3 (-2 + y)

Out[5]= l + 1/3 a (-2 + y)
```

Answer (score 2):

Try (Thanks to  MichaelE2`s comment)

```
Solve[{b == a x + l, y == 3 x + 2}, {b}, {x}][[1]]
(*{b -> 1/3 (-2 a + 3 l + a y)}*)
```

or

```
Eliminate[{b == a x + l, y == 3 x + 2}, x]
(*-2 a + 3 l + a y == 3 b*)
```

Comment: I think to get the `Solve`-type answer the OP seeks, you should try `Solve[{b == a x + l, y == 3 x + 2}, {b}, {x}]`

Comment: @  MichaelE2 Thanks for your hint. Probably you meant `Solve[{b == a x + l, y == 3 x + 2}, {y}, {x}]`

Comment: The OP asks for `b` as a function of `y`, so solve for `b`, no?

Comment: @ MichaelE2  upss you're right!